# can't show picking image from photo library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Im using image picker for choose photos from photo library. When i click the button it displays photo library. But when i click particular image it dismiss modalView and image won't load to view.

code:

```
-(void)showcamera:(id)sender{

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];

}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    // Dismiss the image selection, hide the picker and

    //show the image view with the picked image

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage *newImage = image;


}
```

Comment: I think its bcoz You are setting newImage after dismissing picker.that's my opinion.and also you have to initialize the image.

Comment: And why are you initialize imagePickerController two time?

Comment: when i use  imagePickerController.allowsEditing=YES; Coding working perfectly. Thanks guys

Comment: When i use imagePickerController.allowsEditing=YES; the image displayed inside rectangle box and navigation bar with choose,cancel button. I dn't want box. How can i cancel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

in .h file

```
{
UIImageView *newImage;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
}
```

in .m file

```
- (void)imageTaped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    imagePicker.allowsEditing =NO;

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

}



-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    //release picker
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    //set image


    newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
    [self.view addSubview:mewImage];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: When i use imagePickerController.allowsEditing=YES; the image displayed inside rectangle box and navigation bar with choose,cancel button. I dn't want box. How can i cancel?

Comment: Sorry in my code i am using image crop function thats why. just do `imagePicker.allowsEditing =NO;` and it will not display that box.

Comment: And you have to change this line `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]` to `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]`

Comment: But how to come back from image..After loading image in view can i add  this line [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   inside button press for cancel

Comment: We have added `[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in cancel button. didnt we? or you mean something else?

Comment: See `imagePickerControllerDidCancel` Method that is used for cancel button action.

Comment: I know that is cancel. But how to use this method for cancel....And i have save button for save the image. But when i load image from library the save button is hiding

Comment: In that case you have to set your imageview size accordingly so can your button will be not overlap. right now your imageview size is similar to image which is large so your button will be below that imageview. resize imageview and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Yes you have to create custom CGRect for your imageview.And for cancel you dont have to create cancel button it is inbuit in imagepicker see at right corner of imageview.

Comment: In imagepicker inbuilt having cancel. But after loading image to view how to cancel?

Comment: ohh Ok then. then just do this `[mewImage removeFromSuperview];` this will remove imageView from view so your image will not display on screen.

Comment: when i use this line [newImage removeFromSuperview]; it shows error use of undeclared identifier. But already we declared.

Comment: That's bcoz you are declaring imageview in pickerview method. add `UIImageView *newImage;` in .h file and in pickerview method only use instant of newImage then it will work fine. bcoz then newImage become global for that class and you can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    imgPicked = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        [imagePickerController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

**Declare this in .h**

```
UIImage *imgPicked;
```

in `ViewDidLoad`

```
imgPicked = [[UIImage alloc]init];
```

Comment: What ? i couldn't get you... Take one

Comment: The image won't display after picking from library

Comment: Your code also working when i use  imagePickerController.allowsEditing=YES;.

Answer (score 0):

Best Way is Add Your `Image` to `UIImageView`,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
     UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(@"As U Want")];
     ImgView.image = image;
    [self.View addSubview: ImgView];


    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```